# How to select a particular object from a postgres jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am storing the assessments of students in a jsonb column call assessment, every row in the database stores the assessments of students for a particular subject, and i am trying to get a query that will help retrieve:
1. A student assessment for a particular subject.
2. All the student assessments for every subject offer by the student.

Here is a same of the result i get when i select all records from the table.

```
[

     {
        "id": "22670f29-1437-4af1-b907-f6940377a851",
        "sessionId": 3,
        "sectionId": 4,
        "subjectId": 8,
        "assessment": [
            {
                "exam": 50,
                "grdae": "A",
                "total": 79,
                "position": "First",
                "student_id": 2,
                "assessment_1": 9,
                "assessment_2": 17,
                "assessment_4": 5,
                "student_name": "Anana Aristotle"
            },
            {
                "exam": 50,
                "grdae": "B",
                "total": 69,
                "position": "Third",
                "student_id": 3,
                "assessment_1": 9,
                "assessment_2": 17,
                "assessment_4": 5,
                "student_name": "Anana Elvis"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "beca9d97-0d0a-4d89-b8c5-c9a6fed812a5",
        "sessionId": 3,
        "sectionId": 4,
        "subjectId": 10,
        "assessment": [
            {
                "exam": 50,
                "grdae": "A",
                "total": 79,
                "position": "First",
                "student_id": 2,
                "assessment_1": 9,
                "assessment_2": 17,
                "assessment_4": 5,
                "student_name": "Anana Aristotle"
            },
            {
                "exam": 50,
                "grdae": "B",
                "total": 69,
                "position": "Third",
                "student_id": 3,
                "assessment_1": 9,
                "assessment_2": 17,
                "assessment_4": 5,
                "student_name": "Anana Elvis"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1ed9c3d6-2482-4b1d-ab59-b77a8933699c",
        "sessionId": 3,
        "sectionId": 4,
        "subjectId": 9,
        "assessment": [
            {
                "exam": 50,
                "grdae": "A",
                "total": 90,
                "position": "First",
                "student_id": 2,
                "assessment_1": 9,
                "assessment_2": 17,
                "assessment_4": 5,
                "student_name": "Anana Aristotle"
            },
            {
                "exam": 50,
                "grdae": "B",
                "total": 69,
                "position": "Third",
                "student_id": 3,
                "assessment_1": 9,
                "assessment_2": 17,
                "assessment_4": 5,
                "student_name": "Anana Elvis"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This result contains assessment for the different subjects, with subjectIds, 8, 9 ,and 10 for two students with ids 2 and 3.

NOTE: `sessionID`,`SectionID` and `subjectId` are also columns in the table call assessment.

I should be able to get this object in return if i want a student with id 2 assessment for a subjectId of 9 and sessionId is 3 and also sectionId is 4:

```
         {
            "exam": 50,
            "grdae": "A",
            "total": 90,
            "position": "First",
            "student_id": 2,
            "assessment_1": 9,
            "assessment_2": 17,
            "assessment_4": 5,
            "student_name": "Anana Aristotle"
         }
```

And i should be a to get this result, if i want a student with id 2 assessment for all three subjectIds, i.e id 8, 9, 10, and sessionId is 3 and also sectionId is 4:

```
[
         {
            "exam": 50,
            "grdae": "A",
            "total": 90,
            "position": "First",
            "student_id": 2,
            "assessment_1": 9,
            "assessment_2": 17,
            "assessment_4": 5,
            "student_name": "Anana Aristotle"
         },
         {
            "exam": 50,
            "grdae": "A",
            "total": 79,
            "position": "First",
            "student_id": 2,
            "assessment_1": 9,
            "assessment_2": 17,
            "assessment_4": 5,
            "student_name": "Anana Aristotle"
        },
        {
            "exam": 50,
            "grdae": "A",
            "total": 79,
            "position": "First",
            "student_id": 2,
            "assessment_1": 9,
            "assessment_2": 17,
            "assessment_4": 5,
            "student_name": "Anana Aristotle"
        }
]
```

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you could minimize your sample data. Is it really necessary to show 9 fields per object do describe your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Minimized your data in the fiddle to:

```
[

     {
        "sessionId": 3,
        "sectionId": 4,
        "subjectId": 8,
        "assessment": [
            {              
                "student_id": 2
            },
            {
                "student_id": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "sessionId": 3,
        "sectionId": 4,
        "subjectId": 10,
        "assessment": [
            {
                "student_id": 2
            },
            {
                "student_id": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "sessionId": 3,
        "sectionId": 4,
        "subjectId": 9,
        "assessment": [
            {
                "student_id": 2
            },
            {
                "student_id": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

---

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8fa9ad47b5dd0d769a9a474595997267)

The first step is to unnest the relevant id information:

```
SELECT
    assessments,
    (elems ->> 'sessionId')::int as session_id,
    (elems ->> 'sectionId')::int as section_id,
    (elems ->> 'subjectId')::int as subject_id,
    (assessments ->> 'student_id')::int AS student_id
FROM
    mytable,
    json_array_elements(jsondata) as elems,
    json_array_elements(elems -> 'assessment') as assessments
```

This results in:

```
assessments      | session_id | section_id | subject_id | student_id
:--------------- | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------:
{"student_id":2} |          3 |          4 |          8 |          2
{"student_id":3} |          3 |          4 |          8 |          3
{"student_id":2} |          3 |          4 |         10 |          2
{"student_id":3} |          3 |          4 |         10 |          3
{"student_id":2} |          3 |          4 |          9 |          2
{"student_id":3} |          3 |          4 |          9 |          3
```

The `json_array_elements()` function unnest the json array into one record per array element. Because there are two nested arrays, you need to call this function twice. You can get the values of each level as you can see within the `SELECT` list.

After that you are able to filter whatever you want within the `WHERE` clause. The resulting records (the relevant assessment objects) can be grouped with `json_agg()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT 
    json_agg(assessments)
FROM (
    -- query from above
) s
WHERE session_id IN (3)
    AND section_id IN (4)
    AND subject_id IN (9) -- only one subject
    AND student_id IN (2)
```

or

```
SELECT 
    json_agg(assessments)
FROM (
    -- query from above
) s
WHERE session_id IN (3)
    AND section_id IN (4)
    AND subject_id IN (8,9,10) -- more subjects
    AND student_id IN (2)
```

Comment: @AnanaAristotle Did this help? If not, what can I do? Otherwise, please do not forget to accept the question to show the problem has been solved. Furthermore, please do not to forget to upvote ALL helpful answers. This honors the time and work each replier invested into your problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for the time spend to come up with this solution, but the query still return an empty value, i don't know what i am doing wrong, i will appreciate more input from you, thanks

Comment: Input from me needs input from you. As you can see at the fiddle, the result is not empty. Try to demonstrate your problem with a fiddle as well, please.

Comment: Even with the whole data from your question: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=923202f702ace3a8fe9eecbf7aa68431

Comment: Everything you did look direct, and i am sure why i can the query return the expected value

Comment: So what should I do? I cannot look into your system ;)

Comment: First please accept and upvote the answer, since it solves the question. :) I would appreciate!

Comment: Please i will appreciate if you the sample database i am working with here, i saw that you, you used a json data type and i am using jsonb, and you stored the whole json i pasted in the question to one field you created, but from my end, the json i pasted was just a response from an API request, so the id, session_id, section_id, subject_id all all table columns as well as the assessment. So please i have created a sample of the table here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b2d7a603149cb83dd1e919e38065583a, can you please give me a solution for this format. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198207/discussion-between-anana-aristotle-and-s-man).